how to extract data from website including all of its internal links in Python
I want to extract all the information from a website including from its internal links for the purpose of ceating chatbot for this website . how can i do this ?
I have scrap the main site like https://www.uetmardan.edu.pk/uetm/ but i want to scrap also all of its internal links data
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url =  https://www.uetmardan.edu.pk/uetm/
response.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.get_text(separator='\n')


Ideally you will find a sitemap, otherwise you can also concentrate on the links contained on the pages. create a set of urls while scraping and follow the ones you haven't scraped yet.
example extraction of the links:
set([link.get('href') for link in soup.select('a[href*="uetmardan.edu.pk/uetm"]')])

